# What are the remaining options for popular/active questions that are closed?

Tags: support, questions

This question [Which type of VirtualBox networking should I use?](https://askubuntu.com/q/95022/622994) is highly voted and quite popular. It seems to be the first source of information when searching for the specific topic on search engine.

I would like to be able to provide a new answer to keep the question 
 up-to-date. Currently I cannot do it, nor do I see an option for migrating the question somewhere else.

Unfortunately the only option is to add comments or edit existing answers.

What are the options for such kind of questions? Is there a way for a closed question to be recognized as valid again or be migrated?

E.g. Consider questions that were closed as off-topic but after 5 years technology advances make them valid again. What should be done for these 
 questions?

Answer (score 7):

This question isn't on topic though. It is a typical example of "primarily opinion based". If you want to keep it up to date, you can always edit one of the existing answers, but it really isn't a question that fits our scope or the SE model.

It is both opinion based *and* is about running a VM on a Mac so any answers would have to be for virtualization solutions that work on a Mac. So it's doubly off topic here.

Now, if you see a question that is indeed on topic today (although I can't really imagine how that would happen), then edit it. [If the question was closed in the last 5 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196078/203101), editing it will put it in a reopen queue. Alternatively, or for older questions, post a question here about it and explain why you feel it should be reopened. If enough people agree with you, they will vote to reopen it.

Comment: @Zanna whoops, you're right, thanks! Apparently, "popular" questions [can still be bumped](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196078/203101) into review but not others.

Comment: Hmm I'm seen that post but I've always wondered about the last point that seems to say that being popular will automatically send a post to the reopen queue - it does not say that any kind of edit will send them there (reading the logic of the list). I don't think I have ever seen a post magically appear in the queue because it is popular!

Comment: @Zanna I don't know how they've implemented that. In any case, the main point stands: if you feel something should be reopened, post on meta about it.

Comment: Sure, I upvoted your answer - just speculating about that third point which seems somewhat related to the question here, and wondering if there is any more information about it anywhere. Maybe the thresholds were/are based on Stack Overflow's level of traffic, so it's simply unlikely that a post on any other site would reach them.

Comment: We may want to re-close it with a more modern reason however. I don't like giving out the feeling that these questions are *off-topic*, they're just things we can't answer in our format. If they had reworded it to "What are the different kinds of VirtualBox networking" it'd probably have been fine. Heck he'd probably have even gotten usage advice.